# How to hide "Some Number" label if {{xyz}} is empty without using java script

Tags: html

```
How to hide "Some Number" label if {{xyz}} is empty without using java script
```

I can do this using java script but not sure about html some help will be greatfull.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without JS. HTML has nothing built in that would do this, and CSS can't travel up the structure to hide a previous sibling.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not a programming language so you can't do any logical stuff only on `html`
you need any programming language that support `condition` if you want it any way in `HTML` then try `Ejs` [doc](https://ejs.co/)